# PHP tagging script

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

I have created this PHP script in Laravel. I have database table with items and in my app I can create tags with different regexes. If regex matches text in description or epoch. I will insert relation into ItemTag table.

My current solution is really slow (few hours to run). I have about 200 000 items and will increase fast. And I have hundreds of tags and each tag uses up to 10 regexes.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Tagger
{
    private $sqlStart;
    private $sql;
    private $sqlCount;

    const MAX_INSERTS_IN_QUERY = 500;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sqlStart = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `item_tag`(`id_item`, `id_tag`) VALUES ";
        $this->sql = "";
        $this->sqlCount = 0;
    }


    public function start()
    {
        $tags = Tag::where('active', 1)->get();
        $items = Item::all();

        // Clear all old tags
        ItemTag::truncate();

        $result = '';
        foreach ($items as $item) {

            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $regexes = $tag->regexes;

                foreach ($regexes as $regex) {
                    if (preg_match('/' . base64_decode($regex->regex) . '/i', $item->description)
                        || preg_match('/' . base64_decode($regex->regex) . '/i', $item->epoch)
                    ) {

                        if ($this->sql != "") {
                            $this->sql .= ",";
                        }

                        $this->sqlCount++;
                        $this->sql .= "(" . $item->id_item . "," . $tag->id_tag . ")";
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            if ($this->sqlCount >= self::MAX_INSERTS_IN_QUERY) {
                $this->executeQuery();
            }
        }

        if ($this->sqlCount > 0) {
            $this->executeQuery();
        }

        return $result;
    }


    private function executeQuery()
    {
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($this->sqlStart . $this->sql);
        $this->sqlCount = 0;
        $this->sql = "";
    }
}
```

*EDIT:* Is this solution faster? It shouldn't be. There are many more selects.

```
public function start()
{
    // Clear all old tags
    ItemTag::truncate();

    $tags = Tag::where('active', 1)->get();

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $regexes = $tag->regexes;

        foreach ($regexes as $regex) {
            $items = Item::where("description", "REGEX", '/' . base64_decode($regex->regex) . '/i')
                ->where("epoch", "REGEX", '/' . base64_decode($regex->regex) . '/i');

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($this->sql != "") {
                    $this->sql .= ",";
                }

                $this->sqlCount++;
                $this->sql .= "(" . $item->id_item . "," . $tag->id_tag . ")";

                if ($this->sqlCount >= self::MAX_INSERTS_IN_QUERY) {
                    $this->executeQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: 1- What is your PHP version? 2- Is case-insensitivity (`i` flag) a real need?

Comment: 1 - I am using PHP 5.6, but I can upgrade to PHP 7, if it helps. 2 - I need case-insensitivy flag, but I can rewrite regexes like this: _/test/i_ -> _/[tT][eE][sS][tT]/_

Comment: It's hard to affect performance without seeing actual regular expressions. So you have to show us something and if you can upgrade, do it right now. PCRE JIT is a feature that comes with PHP 7.0 and its effects would be incomparable.

Comment: A regex search against MySQL will NEVER be able to use indexes on the tables involved. This means it will always be slow. Have you considered natural language search (not sure what sort of regex are being used and whether this makes sense)?  Why ask us if one approach is slower than another?  Test it and find out.

Comment: @revo PCRE JIT would not help here, as the regex search in question is happening in MySQL.

Comment: First code snippet differs from second. @MikeBrant